# Playing video from remote server using HTML

Tags: html, video, remote-server

suppose I have an mp4 sitting on a remote server that I can SSH into. can this file be streamed using the video tag? what would the URL look like?

Answer (score 1):

Very theoretically:

```
ssh://example.com/path/to/some.mp4
```

… but browsers don't implement SSH clients or support for the SSH protocol, so that won't work in practice (although it might be possible to write a browser extension to add support).

If you want to embed the video in a webpage, then make the MP4 available of HTTPS (or HTTP).